# Securing my denormalized Meteor rating system

Tags: javascript, mongodb, security, meteor, denormalization

Here's a tough (for me) and wordy one:

I'm coming to terms with this whole Mongo denormalization thing. I created a rating system where users rate each others' videos. To get an average score for a video, a number between 0 and 10 is added directly to a score field in the video document (in a collection named "Entries") each time a user "reviews" it (using a meteor.methods upsert). Of course, an entry's average score is the sum of all those ratings divided by the total number of reviews. I keep a record of each review in a separate collection anyway.

My problem is ... I don't know how to write this securely. There's really nothing to stop someone from adding a number greater than 10 or less than 0 to the sum (or adding an acceptable number repeatedly).

Can you help? Maybe if I said something like "throw an error if the new number you're trying to update the review sum to (in the Entries document) is not equal to the sum of all of the reviews for this entry stored in the reviews collection ... plus your latest score." But if that's correct, how the heck is that written?

Here's the shared client/server code:

```
//update reviews
Meteor.methods({
  reviewUpsert: function(id, doc) {
    if (!this.userId) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, "You must be logged in to do that.");
    }
    if (Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).emails[0].verified !== true) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Your email must be verified to review. Check your email inbox.")
    }
    if (Meteor.user().status === "suspended") {
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Cannot perform this action while account is suspended.")
    }
    var review = Reviews.findOne(id);
    if (review && doc.reviewer !== this.userId) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, "You don't own that review.");
    }
    if (doc.reviewer !== this.userId) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Cannot create a review for someone else.");
      // alternatively, just set doc.owner = this.userId
    }
    Reviews.upsert(id, doc);
  }
});

//update entry score
Meteor.methods({
    entryScoreUpdate: function(id, doc) {
        Entries.update(id, doc);
    }
});
```

And here's the relevant client-side code:

```
  Meteor.call('reviewUpsert',
    Reviews.findOne({unique_review: reviewer_and_entry}, {}, function(err, result){
      if (result) {
        return result._id;
      }
      if (!result) {
        return null;
      }
    }),
    {date: new Date(), reviewer: Meteor.userId(), entry: Session.get('entryId'), title: entrytitle.title, unique_review: reviewer_and_entry, reviewername: Meteor.user().username, review: reviewfield, score: parseInt(scorefield)}, function(err){
      if (err)
        Alerts.add('Review error: ' + err.reason, 'warning');
      else {
          var reviewAdd = parseInt(scorefield) - lastscore;
          Meteor.call('entryScoreUpdate',         
            {_id: Session.get('entryId')}, {$inc: {reviewsum: reviewAdd, reviewcount: incCount}},
            function(err){
              if (err)
                Alerts.add('Review error: ' + err.reason, 'warning');
              else {
                  var entryforavg = Entries.findOne(Session.get('entryId'));
                  Meteor.call('entryScoreUpdate',         
                    {_id: Session.get('entryId')}, {$set: {avgScore: Number(((entryforavg.reviewsum/entryforavg.reviewcount)*10).toFixed(2))}},
                    function(err){
                      if (err)
                        Alerts.add('Review error: ' + err.reason, 'warning');
                      else {
                        Alerts.add('Review has been updated.', 'success'),
                        Session.set("formStatus", 'oldForm');
                      }
                    }
                  );
              }
            }
          );
      }
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
Meteor.methods({
    reviewUpsert : function(id, doc){
        ...
        if( (doc.rating > 10) || (doc.rating < 0) ){
            throw new Meteor.Error( ... )
        }
    }
})
```

As for stopping the same user from entering a rating repeatedly, you will have to track which users have rated which videos and update their rating instead of simply adding new ratings blindly.

Comment: Thanks for this part. I track user ratings in the code above, but in order to get an average and display a reactive list of those averages, I kind of have to duplicate that in the video document. And to do that, I have to allow users access to video documents. That's where the security problem begins. Unless you are saying to store each rating in an array in the video document, and not to have a collection just for ratings at all.

Comment: Maybe in your ratings collection, you could also include the userIds that are associated to each rating?  This is usually the point at which I put marker to whiteboard and figure out which of the solutions sucks the least. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I don't need to do entries.update as its own Meteor.method to be called on the client. I can just run Entries.update on the server, within the "reviewsupsert" method. That way I never actually give users access to edit other users' videos. They just edit their reviews and the server edits the video's average.